# Create a non-admin user group with the ability in install print drivers on server

Tags: drivers, printing, windows-server-2008-r2, administration

I am using windows 2008 RS2. I am trying to setup a poweruser group for printer administrators that has the ability to install printer drivers on a various print servers. I am not sure how to go about this. I assume there must be a group policy under user configuration that allows the installation of printer drivers. I have yet to find it though. If someone has done this before please feel free to let me know how to acheive this goal. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Start `secpol.msc`, then navigate to **Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment**. The **Load and unload device drivers** policy is probably what you were looking for.

Comment: Installing drivers is one of those things that basically requires a high security privilege.  Some drivers interact directly with the kernel.  Installing a driver therefor could result in any other security systems being bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common requirement on Win7 desktops -- letting regular users install printers -- and the same approach works for servers. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/df21d2c2-c2d4-4107-bfe3-bf8c5a1cd946/install-printer-without-being-administrator?forum=w7itprosecurity  discusses it in depth, but the short answer is to edit group policy with GPEDIT.MSC, and the setting is at

```
Computer Configuration> Policies > Administrative Templates > System > Driver Installation and is called " "Allow non-administrators to install drivers for these devices setup classes"
```

As the page I linked notes:

> You will need to add the device class GUID of printers. The GUIDs can
>   be found here:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553426(v=vs.85).aspx